# Cisco AnyConnect client removes default gateway after disconnect, but only on Intel Ethernet Adapter not on wireless connection

Tags: vpn, routing, gateway, cisco-anyconnect

I recently installed Intel Gigabit CT Network Adapter on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. Previously, I was using wireless connection and Cisco AnyConnect VPN client ver 3.1.0165. When trying connect to VPN at work, I am connecting successfully first, but then I get disconnected and fail to reconnect. This is a known issue with our Cisco server. It always disconnects and then reconnects within first couple minutes. If I am connected to my router at home using wireless connection, everything works fine. It gets disconnected and then reconnects automatically and stays connected. But if I am connecting using new Intel adapter, it fails to reconnect. I traced this problem to the fact that when Cisco client disconnects, it removes my default gateway route. I cannot figure out why it doing this only if I am connected through the Ethernet adapter and not through wireless. I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling drivers for the network card. The only thing that helps afterwards is disabling and then enabling back adapter, but it's not helping with re-connecting to VPN. Here is configuration and routes before connecting to VPN:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.ct.comcast.net
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 68-05-CA-24-F6-F9
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a9c5:1e77:aa50:1ade%55(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.49(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, July 19, 2014 11:11:25 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, July 26, 2014 11:11:25 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 929564106
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-C5-00-D6-18-03-73-AE-4A-21

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 75.75.75.75
                                   75.75.76.76
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

routes:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
55...68 05 ca 24 f6 f9 ......Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter
26...38 59 f9 6a 55 59 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
12...38 59 f9 6a 55 59 ......DW1501 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
 1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
56...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
42...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        10.0.0.49     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
        10.0.0.49  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

After it connects to VPN (briefly) the VPN adapter is added:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : INS.INSURITY.NET
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client V
irtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-05-9A-3C-7A-00
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::256f:91f:8caf:be2c%25(Preferred)
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c78:328e:3048:7269%25(Preferred)
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.240.224(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
                                     172.23.240.1
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.159.139
                                     172.25.159.221
 Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 172.25.159.220
 Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 172.25.159.221
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

and routes look like this:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 25...00 05 9a 3c 7a 00 ......Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Mi
niport Adapter for Windows x64
 55...68 05 ca 24 f6 f9 ......Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter
 26...38 59 f9 6a 55 59 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 12...38 59 f9 6a 55 59 ......DW1501 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 41...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 56...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 42...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        10.0.0.49     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.23.240.1   172.23.240.224      2
      4.30.219.65  255.255.255.255         10.0.0.1        10.0.0.49     11
         10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49     11
        10.0.0.49  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     172.23.240.0    255.255.252.0         On-link    172.23.240.224    257
   172.23.240.224  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.23.240.224    257
   172.23.243.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.23.240.224    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    172.23.240.224    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.23.240.224    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.23.240.1       1
===========================================================================
```

and routes look like this:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
        10.0.0.49  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.49    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

At this point I already lost default gateway and connection to Internet. Again, if I connect using wireless adapter default gateway is not lost after disconnecting from VPN.
Here are setting for wireless adapter:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.ct.comcast.net
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : DW1501 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 38-59-F9-6A-55-59
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5932:84c:e3f5:5eae%12(Preferred)
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.94(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, July 19, 2014 9:59:29 PM
 Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, July 27, 2014 12:09:21 AM
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
 DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
 DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 221796857
 DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-C5-00-D6-18-03-73-AE-4A-21

 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 75.75.75.75
                                     75.75.76.76
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Any ideas on what configuration setting is causing this?